# Pulse waveform for 2-qubit circuit

Tags: programming, qiskit, openpulse

I'm trying to reproduce the Bell-state pulse display as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_as5PufUiU).
The code is very short:

```
bell = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
bell.h(0)
bell.cx(0,1)
qc = transpile(bell,backend)
sched_circ = schedule(qc,backend)
sched_circ.draw()
```

but if I use the backend `ibmq_armonk` there are not enough qubits and, for `ibmq_qasm_simulator`, Qiskit-pulse is not supported.
Is there a way to get it working? I do not need to run the waveforms on a device - I just want to analyze them.

P.S. If anyone has a compact IO protocol writing/reading scheduler pulses for multi-qubit Qiskit circuits in HD5 format I'd be interested to collaborate.

Follow up:
After I upgraded my qiskit to ver 0.25.3 the  backend=FakeOpenPulse2Q() works exactly as suggested below.
Thanks for the help.
Jan

Answer (score 1):

You can use *fake pulse backend* to do this.

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeOpenPulse2Q
backend = FakeOpenPulse2Q()
from qiskit import transpile, schedule 
bell = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
bell.h(0)
bell.cx(0,1)
qc = transpile(bell,backend)
pulse_schedule = schedule(qc, backend)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 10))
pulse_schedule.draw('IQXDebugging', axis = ax, show_waveform_info = True)
```

You will get something like below:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot.  A minor follow-up. I run a stand-alone python script (no Jupyter). Is there a way to control the Matplotlib 'ax' - the default sched_circ.draw()  takes all the screen.
Idealy, I'd like sth like this:
'''import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
sched_circ.draw(plot_range=[0, 400],ax=ax)
plt.show()
'''
but 'ax' or 'axis' is not on the list of sched_circ.draw.__code__.co_varnames

Comment: I edited the answer to include the change of fig size. :)  Also look here for more details: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.pulse.Schedule.html#qiskit.pulse.Schedule.draw

Comment: thank you for the advice - all work for me now as I wanted. (My Qiskit vers was too old - I updated it). If anyone is interested in collaborating on storing multi-qubit circuit waveforms as HD5 please contact me.